# Avoid create extra childs Firebase

Tags: validation, firebase, rules

Im a new in firebase and I wish to know how to figure out a question regarding to hasChildren() RuleDataSnapshot and how validates the data will be created.

Sample of db :

```
 {
  "visitors" : {

   "-KP4BiB4c-7BwHwdsfuK" : {
      "mail" : "aaa@mail.com",
      "name" : "aaa",
    }
    .....
}
```

Rules :

```
{
    "rules": {
        "visitors": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth.uid != null",
                "$unique-id": {
                    ".read": "auth != null ",
                    ".write": "auth != null",
                    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name','mail'])",
            }
        }

    }
}
```

As far I know if I want to create data, the data fields must have the same names to pass the rule validation.
For example : 
If I change "name" per "names" and I try to create a new node with their childs the rule works as far I could understand.
I wondering  ¿ what happend if I add manually a new fields to create ?

For example :

```
//Add extra fields which are not actually present
 var data = {name : "xxx",mail:"xxx@mail.com",extra1:222,extra:333};
 firebase.database().ref('visitors/').push(data);
```

The result is :

```
  "visitors" : {
  "-KP4BiB4c-7BwHwdsfuK" : {
      "mail" : "aaa@mail.com",
      "name" : "juan",
     "extra1":222,
      "extra2":333
    }
}
```

So my question is how to avoid create extra childs per node ? I supposed the rule did it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your validate rule says your post must have **atleast** those children and not **only** those children.
To ensure no other children can be added you have to add the following to your rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "visitors": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null",
        "$unique-id": {
            ".read": "auth != null ",
            ".write": "auth != null",
            //This line says the new data must have ATLEAST these children
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name','mail'])",   
            //You can add individual validation for name and mail here     
            "name": { ".validate": true },
            "mail": { ".validate": true },
            //This rule prevents validation of data with more child than defined in the 2 lines above (or more if you specify more children)
            "$other": { ".validate": false }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Take a look [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-advanced-example) for another example.