# Lock down the database structure of firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am new to firebase and I am building a small SPA. 
I could set the security rules like the following. (Only authenticated user can read or write his own projects.)

```
{
 "rules": {
 "users":{
  "$uid":{
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

This works fine but when I sign in to my app, inspect the source code and try adding hidden extra objects in **project form**, firebase still accept it.

[image: inspect tool]

[image: firebase database]

In this screenshot, the objects such as **blablab, blablabla** are added from Chrome's inspect tool.

As the data structure has to be like

**users-->userId-->projects-->unquieKey-->project_title**

But after I added it, the db structure is messed up.

I want to know that how can I prevent someone sending extra data or spam objects?

Comment: after you sign in you are able to send data since you are an authenticated user

Comment: Does it mean that every user (who are authenticated) are possible to send spam data to the database? I think there will be a good option to secure it. Perhaps, I don't know it yet.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38946468/4916627) about validating the data structure in your firebase rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use this:

```
 {
"rules": {
  "users":{
     "$uid":{
      ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }
   }
 }
}
```

It means only authenticated users can read and write to the database. So every user who was authenticated will be able to send data to the database. To prevent spam, you need to think of a way(maybe a function that prevents user to write specific words to the database)

You can also use validation, that can help a bit:

```
  {
 "rules": {

     ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"

  } 
 }
```

more details here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

You can use this:

```
  {
 "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false

   }
 }
```

to prevent anyone from sending data